# how to when clicked the "next" button show next item in horizantal recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list for recyclerview and it has a button for the next item. When I clicked button recyclerview doesn't see. How will I make it? Like this:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
int index = 0;
for(Point point: points) {
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
    index ++;
}
```

Comment: did you try **`recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`**

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I added some code